# Which StringBuilder function can be used to replace every first * with another character?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have used continue to skip the next iteration but it isn't working,

- my output    : value of string : !! EODC Ot EMOCLEw  .
- expected o/p : value of string : !! EODC Ot EMOCLEw *.

Code snippet:

```
public static StringBuilder replace_ast(StringBuilder sb)
{
    for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++)
    {
        if(sb.charAt(i)=='*')
        {
            sb.setCharAt(i,' ');
            continue;
        }
    }
    return sb;
}

main()
{
    String s="!!*EDOC*Ot*EMOCLEw**.";
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(s);
    sb=Remove_asterisk.replace_ast(sb);
    System.out.println("value of string : "+sb);
}
```

Comment: Continue skips **to** the next iteration. And even if that would work, it wouldn't work with *** anyhow.

Comment: Yes it does and that is what I want so that it can skip the next asterisk encountered.

Comment: is there any other option I can go with other than continue to get the desired output?

Comment: Well you can for example have a variable called skipNext...

Answer (score 0):

Is the StringBuilder part relevant? This just seems like a whole bunch of needless copying into a datatype that doesn't have the API you want.

(Also, in java we `writeVariablesLikeThis`, `not_like_this`. If you want help / write code others can read, follow conventions).

```
String s = "!!*EDOC*Ot*EMOCLEw**.";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(replaceAst(s));
String t = "****";
System.out.println(t);
System.out.println(replaceAst(t));


static String replaceAst(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\*(\\**)", " $1");
}
```

Seems to be working:

```
!!*EDOC*Ot*EMOCLEw**.
!! EDOC Ot EMOCLEw *.
****
 ***
```

Those arguments to replaceAll are regular expressions. `\\*` is regexp-ese for 'a star character'. `()` is regexpese for: "Remember what you matched inside these and let me refer back to it with $1". Just `*` is '0 to many of these'. (Thus, `\\**` is regexpese for 0 to many star characters). In other words, that regexp says: 1 star, followed by any number of further stars, and let me refer to the additional stars as $1.

Then we replace that construct with space + those additional stars, if any. Resulting in exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you want:

```
import java.util.*;
class Remove_asterisk   
{   
    public static StringBuilder replace_ast(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<sb.length(); i++)
        {
            if (sb.charAt(i)=='*')
            {
                sb.setCharAt(i,' ');
                while (i<sb.length()-1 && sb.charAt(i+1)=='*')
                    ++i; // This will skip all the upcoming *'s
            }
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String s = "!!*EDOC*Ot*EMOCLEw**.";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        sb = Remove_asterisk.replace_ast(sb);
        System.out.println("Value of string : "+sb);
    }
}
```

Example: When we are at i=18, an `*` is found so we replace it will   and move to i=20 as we have nothing to do with the next asterisk.

O/P : `Value of string : !! EDOC Ot EMOCLEw *.`
Feel free to ask any doubt.

Comment: Generally just posting code is not really a good idea (try to explain a few things). More specifically, this is not the right answer. Try as input `String s = "***";` and you'll see why your algorithm doesn't quite get the job done.

Comment: Ok. Misunderstood the question a bit. It works fine now. Thanks for pointing it out.